# throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name); ^ MongooseError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "merchant"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
  throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
  ^
```

MongooseError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "merchant".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (C:\survey-system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:362:13)

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var index = require('./routes/index');

require('./models/merchant');

var mongoose = require('mongoose').model('merchant');
var merchant = require('./routes/merchant');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/SK');

var app = express();
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/SK');
var merchant = mongoose.model('merchant');

router.get('/merchant', function(req, res, next) {
  merchant.find({},function(err, docs){
                res.send('index',{docs:docs})
        });
  });
```

**model/merchant.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var merchantSchema = new Schema({

id              :Number, 
merchant_id     :{type: [String], index: true },
merchant_name   :String,
merchant_type   :String,
contact_name    :String,
phone           :String,
email           :String,
Address         :String,

created_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});


var merchant  = mongoose.model('merchant', merchantSchema);

exports =merchant;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare the `mongoose.connect` above the model imports

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/SK');


var MerchantModel = require('./models/merchant');

//  var mongoose = require('mongoose').model('merchant');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var merchant = require('./routes/merchant');


var app = express();
```