# Mongoose, can't print products from database

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have problem with print items in console.log or res.json from database.

what am I doing wrong

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var productSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    price: Number
});

var product = mongoose.model('product, productSchema');
mongoose.connect(db);
var db = 'mongodb://localhost/product';

router.get('/books', function(req, res) {
    console.log('getting all products');

    product.find({})
        .exec(function(err, product) {
            if (err) {
                res.send('errror');
            } else {
                console.log(product);
                res.json(product);
            }
        })
});
```

name of database products is : `db.product`
Thanks

> Error:
>   C:\Users\Turqus\Desktop\node\products\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:382
>         throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
>         ^
>   MongooseError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "product, productSchema".
>   Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
>       at Mongoose.model (C:\Users\Turqus\Desktop\node\products\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:382:13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the Database Connection first.

change this

`var product = mongoose.model('product, productSchema');`

to

`var product = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);`

`mongoose.model()` accepts two parameter the name of the collection your model is for and the 2nd the `Schema`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var productSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    price: Number
});

var product = mongoose.model('product', 'productSchema');

router.get('/books', function(req, res) {
console.log('getting all products');

product.find({})
    .exec(function(err, product) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('errror');
        } else {
            console.log(product);
            res.json(product);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: You have to make the db connection first, This will help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468201/throw-new-mongoose-error-missingschemaerrorname-mongooseerror-schema-hasn/42468380#42468380

Comment: Ok thanks, I have question, how to change base because i download nothing 
look
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a0e3523252560a18adfaa03f2895d7f8

Comment: whats the name of database which have the data titled: wisnia as in gist

Comment: name is db.product

Comment: db.product means the `product` collection, it doesn't tell `db`
just type `db` in terminal and tell what it prints

Comment: there is written  'test'

Comment: okay. that should work fine then, have you made connection to any other db in code, might be this one `    mongoose.connect(db);
    var db = 'mongodb://localhost/product'` overriding the the `test` database

Comment: Yes, but i Have before router.get 
"var product = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);
var db = 'mongodb://localhost/product';
mongoose.connect(db);"

And still he is downading empty: []
GET /product/books 304 7.619 ms - -

Comment: just remove "var product = mongoose.model('product', productSchema); var db = 'mongodb://localhost/product'; mongoose.connect(db);" and try

Comment: getting all products
GET /product/books 500 21.725 ms - 1086
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/88e46ba9130316fab9b8b2d1f97bba8d
now he cant find

Comment: check mine comment try that code

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/88e46ba9130316fab9b8b2d1f97bba8d

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var productSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  price: Number
});

var product = mongoose.model('product', 'productSchema');

router.get('/books', function(req, res) {
  console.log('getting all products');

  product.find({ })
    .then((data) => { res.send(data) })
    .catch((err) => { res.send(err) });
});
```

Or

```js
var products = await product.find({ }).exec();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.