# Why do I get a 'MissingSchemaError' when trying to populate a Mongoose model in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

**Mongoose Typescript - Schema hasn't been registered for model "X" although X has been declared in other file.**

I have 2 schema named "User" and "Portfolio" in 2 different files:

```
//User.model.ts
import mongoose, {Types, Schema} from "mongoose";

export interface IUser {
    name: string,
    portfolios: Types.ObjectId[],
}
export interface IUserModel extends IUser, Document {}

const userSchema = new Schema<IUserModel>({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    portfolios: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Portfolio"
    }],

})
export const User = mongoose.model<IUserModel>('User', userSchema)

//Portfolio.model.ts
import mongoose, {Types, Schema} from "mongoose";
export interface IPorfolio{
    name: string,
    users: Types.ObjectId[], 
}
export interface IPorfolioModel extends IPorfolio, Document {}
export const portfolioSchema = new Schema<IPorfolioModel>({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    users: [{
        type: Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    }],    
})
export const Portfolio = mongoose.model<IPorfolioModel>('Portfolio', portfolioSchema)`
```

My get function is a generic function like

```
getAll = (model: Model<any>, selectedFields: string, populatedFields: string[]) => (req:Request, res: Response) => {
        console.log("Reading all docs...");
        model
            .find<Array<Document>>()
            .select(selectedFields)
            .populate(populatedFields || [])
            .then((result: object[])=>{
                // console.log(result);
                let results: object[] = []
                result.forEach(ele => {
                    results.push(snakeToCamel(ele))
                })
                res.status(httpCode.ok).send({
                    code: httpCode.ok,
                    message: "OK",
                    data: result,
                })
            })
    }
//call function
getUsers = genericFunction.getAll(User,"name portfolios",["portfolios"])
```

I want to receive result like:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "1",
            "name": "System Admin",
            "portfolios": [
                {
                    "_id": "2",
                    "name": "PORTFOLIO",
                }
             ]
         }
]
```

But it throw Error:

```
throw new MongooseError.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Portfolio".
```

When I copy all the code in Portfolio.model.ts into the User.model.ts, it works, but I don't know the reason why?
I have try to import the PortfolioSchema and PorfolioModel by using "import" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468201/throw-new-mongoose-error-missingschemaerrorname-mongooseerror-schema-hasn

Comment: @LinDu I've tried but the error still happened

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with Typescript behavior when it comes to unused imports. Because your User model is actually being referenced where it is being imported to, the code in your module will run to register it as a mongoose schema.

`getUsers = genericFunction.getAll(User,"name portfolios",["portfolios"])`

Vice versa for portfolio - Portfolio is not getting referred to in any way -> code will not run -> no registering "Portfolio" as a mongoose schema. This happens in Typescript because if you have "import Portfolio from '..'" in your code but no references to Portfolio, the typescript compiler will notice this and basically tree shake this import statement out of its output. Check your `dist` for the emitted file and see if there is a require or import statement (depending on your tsconfig) for the Portfolio module in there to confirm.

I encountered this issue myself. Assuming you never have a need to reference Portfolio directly in your code to do any queries and it exists only to populate subdocuments, you can fix this by simply changing

`import Portfolio from './location/file'`

to

`import './location/file'`

Dynamic imports also work

`const Portfolio = import('./location/file')`

or simple require statements

`const Portfolio = require('./location/file')`

It is mentioned in [Microsoft's TypeScript FAQ here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit)